# Add SSD to the existing system

Tags: gnome, hard-drive, ssd

I have Ubuntu Gnome installed on my laptop and I will add a SSD in addition to the current configuration.
Is there any way to move the system from the HDD to the SSD and keep the HDD as a simple storage unit?

Comment: Install Ubuntu on SSD, move files from HDD to SSD, format hard disk?

Comment: @alex2003super I would like to keep the configuration, packages, etc I have installed on the actual system. Sorry if it's a newbie question, this is my first interaction with Linux as a day-to-day operating system.

Comment: no, after this clarification I may assure you it's not a newbie question. Honestly I don't know if that is even possible (I'm not a great expert in this field though)

Comment: Now that I think about it, you may very easily clone the Hard drive to the SSD entirely. I did it with my PC after buying an SSD and it worked flawlessly. You can use Clonezilla for this. Note that if SSD is smaller than HDD it's gonna be harder. Also it causes some unnecessary wear on the SSD.

Comment: It should be as simiple as restoring you normal backup to a new install after system has failed. You do have that backup? If not you at least need that even if cloning. Almost all your settings (unless server) are in /home so that is first thing to backup.  While /home will have settings and data whether inside / or separate /home partition, you need a list of installed apps. https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages And if you manually edited a config file in /etc back those up. I normally recommend new install as that is also a major houseclean & restore data.

Comment: @oldfred I agree with you. Copying \Program Files\ data to a new PC shouldn't be done on Windows, on Linux (if even possible) an equivalent process would cause more headaches than else. Data cloning works well and it applies to whatever configuration you may happen to have - as long as the destination drive is equal or lager than original one in size. If it's not you'll have to shrink your partition, copy it to the destination and then repair the grub.